# Remove rows with double timestamps, which have NaN in data

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, duplicates, nan

I have a pandas dataframe with a pandas datetime (I created that datetime with pandas.to_datetime) and a value of a variable:

`datetime                   value
 2018-10-01 00:00:00        231
 2018-10-01 00:01:00        233
 2018-10-01 00:01:00        NaN
 2018-10-01 00:02:00        220`

I want to delete the rows with double timestamp and NaN, I tried several possibilities like `pd.Series(df['datetime']).duplicated(keep='first')` but it is not always the first one neither the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if column `df['datetime']` is `duplicated` with an `&` condition which checks if `df['value']` is `nan`

```
df[~(df['datetime'].duplicated(keep=False) &  df['value'].isna())]
```

Comment: Thank you!
So I extract the data that is double and NaN, is there a way to select exactly the others or is it better to do that first and then delete these lines from the df?

Comment: @Betty sorry I didnt get your question , did it not work or ..? "a way to select exactly the others " what does this mean

Comment: Your code works, it selects all the entries in the df which are duplicated and have NaN in the value. But I actually want to remove these from the df

Comment: I think @Betty meant they are looking for the opposite, of what your code retains, namely: `df[~(df['datetime'].duplicated(keep=False) &  df['value'].isna())]`

Comment: @DarrylG ohh , I see Thank you :) yeah then inverse that operation would work

Comment: Yes I meant that! Thank you!